# Live disk based computer

Tags: linux, hard-drive, liveusb

So while I am waiting for my terabyte external hd to format I figured it would be worth my time to double check if the project I have planned for it is likely to work. My plan is to load an os (that is capible of live booting) on the hd and use it like you would any other live disk with one major difference, I would be able to store files on the hd as well as my machine. I was going to use Puppy Linux for the os (because it apparently does so well with live booting) but I am either going to go with Tails, BackTrack Linux, or good old Ubuntu. So my question is: is this likely to work? Will I end up with a little portable personal computer that I can open up I can find a computer? Or will I just end up with a live disk with way to much empty space on it?

What I am looking for in answers is this: an answer to the will it work question, any problems I am likely to run into, and, if acceptable, where anyone has done this before (I looked myself already but I could only find vague answers and incomplete message board conversations).

Note: I realize that someone will mention the bottleneck that exists with using a USB hd. I know it is there, I am using USB 3.0 to minimize that, and I am not going to be working with supper huge files anyway.

Comment: Tails, Backtrack (now called Kali), and ubuntu are miles apart.  Are you going for anonymity in your communications or what? USB3 SSD would be even faster.

Comment: The reason for tails and/or Kali was that I was going to try out a new os that I haven't played with before. I will likely go with Ubuntu.